# globalize with search_cop - unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, globalize

I'm trying to use the `globalize` gem and `search_cop` together. In my model I have:

```
class Museum < ApplicationRecord
  include SearchCop

  has_one_attached :hero_image
  translates :name, :address, :description, :facilities, :hours, :tickets

  search_scope :search do
    attributes :name, :address
    options :name, :type => :fulltext
    options :address, :type => :fulltext
  end
end
```

But when I go to search I get:

```
irb(main):006:0> Museum.search("art")
SearchCop::UnknownAttribute: Unknown attribute museums.name
```

Is it possible to use Globalize and SearchCop together? if so, how do I specify the translated fields to search on?

Comment: Try to add  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations` to your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Globalize with SearchCop you need to define the translated attributes through their association. So something like:

```
search_scope :search do
  attributes name: "translations.name", address: "translations.address"
  options :name, :type => :fulltext
  options :address, :type => :fulltext
end
```